# How to count local variable indexes in MethodVariableAccess?

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation, byte-buddy, jvm-bytecode

According to [1], in a method frame, the local variable array contains a reference to the called instance, the parameters and, finally, any other variables used in the method's code. Also, `long` and `double` values occupies two local variables.

When using Byte Buddy to generate the method's code via stack manipulations, does the `MethodVariableAccess.OffsetLoading` index `long` and `double` values into a single index or is it needed, as using ASM directly, to account for these kinds of values to calculate a local var index?

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MethodVariableAccess.OffsetLoading` accesses an offset which is not named index to distinguish exactly that. If a `long` or `double` type is contained in the array, this accounts to two slots. Byte Buddy uses this abstraction to interact with ASM where the same offset is required for calling the respective visitor.